# Why doesn't the return statement exit the while loop, backing up to the very first line of the while loop instead?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I have been learning the binary search tree recently and here is one implementation of the tree. I was wondering why the return statement won't exit the while loop but literally returns to the first line of the loop. Here is the code in the debugger mode with IntelliJ[Code Snippet in Debugger Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhnp2.png).

```
public class BinaryTree {
    Node root;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();

    bt.insert(3, "root");
    bt.insert(2,"left");
    bt.insert(1,"leftchild");


}

public void insert(int value, String name) {
    Node newNode = new Node(value, name);
    if (root == null) {
        root = newNode;
    } else {
        Node focusNode = root;

        Node parent;

        while (true) {

            parent = focusNode;


            if (value < focusNode.value) {
                focusNode = focusNode.left;

                    if(focusNode == null) {
                        parent.left = newNode;
                        return;
                    }
            } else {
                focusNode = focusNode.right;
                if(focusNode == null) {
                    parent.right = newNode;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }



}
```

After finding that the left child of the node at level one is not empty, the execution "returns" itself to the first line of the while loop and assigns the left child mentioned before to the parent node; the parent node was the root before.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You are seeing another execution of the method (probably because of the repeated `insert` calls).

Comment: How did you determine that the `return` statement is going back to the start of the loop? Are you single-stepping this in the debugger?